# Automated Plant Harvesting Algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary

I am trying to write an algorithm to instruct a robotic arm to harvest plants. In order to do this I need to create a class for the plant locations which logs their location in three dimensional space as well as the time since that location was last harvested. I have already written code that generates a dictionary which gives each plant location a "code" (e.g. p1, p2, p3, etc.) as well as it's location in spherical coordinates (i.e. radius and phi). I need to take this dictionary and convert each entry into a class instance.

Below is the algorithm for generating the dictionary. It would be in the format 'p1': (10, 1), 'p2': (10, 2), 'p3': (10, 3), 'p4': (20, 1), 'p5': (20, 2), etc.

I need to take this dictionary and create an instance of the class "Plant" for every entry. Below is the Plant class. delta_t is the time since last harvest which will be used to determine whether or not the robotic arm should skip over that location and move onto a more mature plant that is ready to be harvested but for now I will leave that field blank.

```
class Plant:
    def __init__(self,phi,r,delta_t):
        self.r=r
        self.phi=phi
        self.delta_t=delta_t
```

The desired format is:

```
p1=Plant(10,1)
p2=Plant(10,2)
p3=Plant(10,3)
p4=Plant(20,1)
```

and so on...

How do I achieve this without typing every instance out by hand. Everything from the phi and r values as well as the number of plants to be harvested must be able to change at any time so writing it out manually does not make sense.

I have tried iterating over the dictionary with setattr() as well as every other solution that I could readily comprehend. I am new to programming so there is much I don't know.

```
#generates an array of phi values
angular_iterations=[]
phi_i=10
phi_f=270
delta_phi=10
for i in range(1,4):
    for i in range (phi_i,int(phi_f+delta_phi),delta_phi):
        angular_iterations.append(i)
angular_iterations.sort()
print(angular_iterations)

#generates an array of radial values
walkway_width=2
tank_width=2
row_length=3
interplant_disp=1
centrifugal_iterations=[]
while len(centrifugal_iterations)<len(angular_iterations):
    for i in range (1,(row_length)+1):
        centrifugal_iterations.append(i)
print(centrifugal_iterations)

#combines phi and r to make a 2D array
phi_r=list(zip(angular_iterations,centrifugal_iterations))
print(phi_r)
print("Lists zipped")

#creates a list of plant codes "p"+n where (n) is an integer indicating the harvest order
print("generating plant codes")
plant_codes=[]
length_phi_r=len(phi_r)
while len(plant_codes)<len(phi_r):
    for i in range(1,length_phi_r+1):
        code="p"+str(i)
        plant_codes.append(code)
print(plant_codes)
print("plant codes printed")
print(length_phi_r)

#generates a dictionary using the plant codes and phi_r values
print("generating dictionary")
plant_dictionary={}
zip_code_phir=zip(plant_codes,phi_r)
plant_dictionary=dict(zip_code_phir)
print(plant_dictionary)
print("dictionary generated")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`dictionary comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (docs are about `list comprehensions` but `dictionary comprehensions` use the same idea):

```py
plant_dictionary = {k: Plant(v[0], v[1]) for k, v in plant_dictionary.items()}
```

Alternatively you can just set the values of a dictionary directly:

```py
for key, value in plant_dictionary.items():
    plant_dictionary[key] = Plant(value[0], value[1])
```

Comment: Thank you! I have seen this before but it did not register as a solution. I will try this and get back to you on the results.

Comment: Ok progress has been made but when I try to retrieve the values for an entry: print(p1.phi) I get the error "NameError: name 'p1' is not defined". Do you know how I would fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should access the values in the dictionary: `plant_dictionary['p1'].phi`